# Are .CARTO files exported from CARTO Builder proprietary completely?

Tags: geojson, carto

I'm trying to get all my mapping data out of CARTO, but all that exports is .CARTO.

Is there a non-proprietary format that I can export it to?

Comment: You may want to edit this post and remove the negative connotations and simply ask what you are trying to do, as it seems to have attracted downvotes.

Answer (score 7):

If your problem is about exporting data from CARTO. On the one hand, you can export your datasets as `GeoJSON`, `csv`, `shapefile`, `KML` or `SVG` using CARTO UI or CARTO [SQL API](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/sql-api). On the other, you can export your maps as CARTO files. CARTO files are basically a zip with two files: a `GeoPackage` and a `JSON`, containing the `vizjson` configuration. **You can unzip it and work just with the `GPKG`**.

Comment: So what you're saying is that '.CARTO' files aren't proprietary, but that .CARTO (with its .gpkg) has replaced more commonly used export filetypes (`.shp`, `.kml`, `geojson`) for the spatial **and** the non-geospatial data (together, not separate) that were previously available as options in Carto Builder. Did I get that right? I'm aware you can export your non-geospatial data as other filetypes. But I'm asking specifically about exporting the geospatial data with the attributes you've added in CARTO as additional data fields. I ask because previously you could export

Comment: In Editor, you were able to export your data(sets) to shapefiles, kmls, csvs and so on, your maps, on the other hand, could be exported as .carto files and also get the vizjson. You can do the same in BUILDER, except the last thing. But this is a temporary limitation (until the new CARTO.js library will be released).